# How to split String by comma in SQL Server and Pass it through Loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to split the string and print it through loop.

For example

```
Declare @storeID nvarchar(MAX)
SET @storeID = '1400,2001,2400,1201,1001,1302'

Declare @i int
SET @i=0

while(i<6) //6 is length
Begin
    print @value    
END

OUTPUT
------
1400
2001
2400
1201
1001
1302
```

split the string and print one by one through loop via variable `@value`

Comment: Do you really want to print the result or splitting the string your objective ?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 has string_split() for other versions see the dup link.

Comment: @Prdp I don't need to print. But every time the `@value` should change. For testing purpose only i just want to print

Comment: @AlexK. I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: @mohamedfaisal what if you create a UDF which you can use anywhere and which returns a table ?

Comment: Then here is another dup link [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows/36305493#36305493)